# How to migrate to OpenSearch with CloudFormation without outage?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-elasticsearch, opensearch

I found [this tutorial](https://onecloudplease.com/blog/migrating-to-opensearch-with-cloudformation), however this tutorial has two main drawbacks.

1. A brand new CloudFormation stack would be created
2. There would be outage.

Is there a way to upgrade ES without outage and new stack ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to upgrade ES without outage. Here are the steps:

1. Add only below config in CloudFormation yml file

   UpdatePolicy:
   EnableVersionUpgrade: true
2. Update all other ES configs including version changes.
3. deploy the CloudFormation

Step 3 would do blue-green deployment, so there is no outage.

[related official document.](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-opensearch-upgrade/)